# JSF 'total' variable for datatable

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

I have read the previous post: [JSF 'total' variable something like c:set in JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1559689).  Although the answer suggests that the total should come from the backing bean, I have genuine need to do it in the facelet.  For my case, I want to display a bank book type datatable, with each row consisting of a date, a description, an amount and a **running total**.  The data  come from a JPA get of type List<Entity>.  If I did the total in the backing bean I need to iterate the List, create a data model solely for the purpose of a running-total property.  This is inefficient indeed.

I tried:

```
<c:set var="sum" value="0.0" scope="view" />
    <table>
<ui:repeat value="#{xxxBean.items}" var="item">
    <tr>
        <td><h:outputText value="#{item.date1}" /></td>
        <td><h:outputText value="#{item.desc}" /></td>
        <td><h:outputText value="#{item.amount}" /></td>
    <c:set var="sum" value="${sum+item.amount}"/>
        <td><h:outputText value="${sum}" /></td>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>
    </table>
```

but it does not work, ${sum} resets to zero for each row.  Is there another way, except making a custom component?

Comment: You cannot mix JSTL with JSF in this way.

Answer (score 1):

This still can be solved using a method in the backing bean:

```
public class MyBackingBean {

 private Double runningTotal = 0.0;

 public Double getRunningTotal(Item item) {
   Double result = runningTotal;
   runningTotal += item.getAmount();
   return result;
 }

}
```

Then in your view, use this to display the running total:

```
<td><h:outputText value="#{xxxBean.getRunningTotal(item)}" /></td>
```

Not elegant, but it works.

Comment: No, it does not work.  #{xxxBean.getRunningTotal(item)} is unacceptable, only #{xxxBean.runningTotal} - no argument getRunningTotal()

Comment: What version of JSF are you using? In JSF 2 you can pass arguments to method expressions.

Comment: I use Mojarra 2.0.2 on tomcat 6.0.

Comment: Argument support was added in EL 2.2 - so you need Tomcat 7 and Servlet 3.0 support turned on.   (This is EL in general - impacting both JSTL *and* JSF) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273729/how-to-call-a-method-with-a-parameter-in-jsf